# Select 2 counts from the same table with a foreign key involved

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I'm having quite some trouble doing this query which I can do completely fine as 2 different queries. So lets get to it.

edit: I'm using PostgreSQL.

I have a `Child` table and a `Classroom` table, child has a FK to `Classroom` called `classroom_id`.

What do I need? Simple a count of all the classrooms, and a count of all the classrooms with at least 2 children in it.

As I said, I could just do this:

```
select
    count(classroom.id) "Total"
from
    classroom
```

and the second can be done in a couple of different ways

```
select
    count(with_students)
from
     (
    select
        classroom.id, count(child.classroom_id) as "students"
    from
        classroom
    inner join child on
        child.classroom_id = classroom.id
    where
        is_active = true
    group by
        classroom.id, child.classroom_id
    having
        count(child.classroom_id) > 1 ) as with_students
```

The problem is, I'm using a tool that won't let me combine 2 different queries to output a single chart, which is what I need.

I've read a bunch and there are tons of examples on doing counts, but I couldn't find any similar to what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: I'm sorry. PostgreSQL I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to calculate the number of students in each classroom -- including no students at all.  Then aggregate again:

```
select count(*) as num_classrooms,
       sum(case when num_students >= 2 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select cr.id, count(ch.classroom_id) as num_students
      from classroom cr left join
           child ch
           on ch.classroom_id = cr.id and
              ch.is_active = true
      group by cr.id
     ) x;
```

Note:  I'm not sure if `is_active` is for the child or the classroom.  This assumes it is for the child.

Comment: Yep that did the trick. Just one typo on the second `count` you should be counting ch.classroom_id.